# jQuery ajax working in chrome but not in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following jQuery snippet works in chrome but not in IE-9
What am I missing. 
First Alert shows in both IE and Chrome but Second one works only in Chrome.

```
getBeaconXML: function ()
{
  var myself = this;
  var beaconUrl = this.beaconXMLUrl;
  alert("Url : " + beaconUrl);

  $.ajax({ 
    async: false,
    url: beaconUrl,                            
    dataType: "xml"
  })
  .done(function (data) {
    alert("Reach done");
    myself.bXML = data;
    myself.parseBeaconId();
    myself.parseUseKey();
    myself.parseBeacons();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ 
In the documentation there is no method `done`. Try `success` or `complete` depending on the task.

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
getBeaconXML: function ()
                    {
                        var myself = this;
                        var beaconUrl = this.beaconXMLUrl;
                        alert("Url : " + beaconUrl);
                        $.ajax(
                        { 
                            async: false,
                            url: beaconUrl,                            
                            dataType: "xml",
                      success: function(data)
                       {
                            alert("Reach done");
                            myself.bXML = data;
                            myself.parseBeaconId();
                            myself.parseUseKey();
                            myself.parseBeacons();
                      }
                        });

                },
```